# Asp.net custom razor view engine specify cshtml file location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewengine

[solution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L5Ad.png)I have several projects with MVC Views, 'TestProject' is the Website Content Directory, 
When I debug, I need build 'Address' project every time if I change cshtml file.
I try to override RazorViewEngine, but it use Virtual Path, I can not use absolute path or relative path like '../../' to location where views/files are placed is out of the project's directory.
It there a way that I can change cshtml file without build?

```
 public class DebugRazor: RazorViewEngine
    {
        public DebugRazor(string relativePath)
        {
            base.ViewLocationFormats = new[] 
            {
                "../" + relativePath + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "../" + relativePath + "/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                "../" + relativePath + "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                "../" + relativePath + "/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
            };
        }
   }
```

RazorViewEngine is implement from VirtualPathProviderViewEngine, here is the same issue:[How to use relative virtual path in custom razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104031/how-to-use-relative-virtual-path-in-custom-razor-view-engine)

Comment: Add some code what you have tried!

Comment: I add some code. thanks.

Comment: format the code and tell clearly what you are wanting.

Comment: I add screenshot and more info about my question, thank a lot.

Comment: Have you tried with this `"~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"`? instead of `"../" + relativePath + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"`

Comment: Yes, but my cshtml file is out of the 'Root' directory, maybe in any other drive, even "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" not throw exception, but can not locate my cshtml files.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't, I am in Business Environment.

Comment: Okay! I no problem!